# detecting sequence of two actions in Epic

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I want to catch the timing:
when FIRST_ACTION dispatched, and then SECOND_ACTION dispatched

currently my code is looking like this. It works well as I intended.

```js
action$.ofType(FIRST_ACTION).pipe(
  mergeMap(() =>
    action$.ofType(SECOND_ACTION).pipe(
      take(1),
      mergeMap(() => /* do something*/),
    )
  )
)
```

Is there any better way to detect timing like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [zip](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/zip).

```
zip(action$.ofType(FIRST_ACTION), action$.ofType(SECOND_ACTION)).pipe(
  mergeMap(([firstAction, secondAction]) => 
    // return observable  
  )
)
```

Are you sure that you will always have a corresponding second action for your first action? Be aware that zip waits for for a value from each source observable before producing a value.